# keyboard back light always on can't turn it off even in the sleep mode

Tags: keyboard

I have a problem with the keyboard backlit; it's always on. It does not turn off even in the sleep mode. The laptop is overpowered 17.

What I have tried:

- to edit files on `/sys/class/leds/input 4::scroll lock`
- the command `xset -led off`

I finaly tried with the latest kernel but that also did not solve the problem.
I *can* disable it from the bios but that's obviously not what I want to do.

Comment: 1 - I have tried to edit files on /sys/class/leds/input 4::scroll lock. and  I have also tried the command xset -led off . and finaly tried with the latest kernel but that also did not solve the problem